# Angular cli:How to prevent hsl color being converted to hex value on build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm truing to add a `hsl` color value to background but that is being converted to `hex` value
How can i configure `angular-cli` that it does not happen.

example app https://stackblitz.com/edit/css-test-z?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create sass functions that return the value as hsl so will not change to hex

```
@function hsla($h, $s, $l) {
  @return unquote('hsl(#{$h}, #{$s}, #{$l})'); // hsla instead of hsl
}

.s{
  background-color: hsla(3, 100%, 61%); ;
}
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/css-test-z-dh6qh3) [Disable converting hsl()/hsla()](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/469)